# TypeError: 'dict_keyiterator' object is not subscriptable - Python 2

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the nth predecessor of an object:

```py
u = G.predecessors(v)[0]
```

But this returns the following error on Python 2:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keyiterator' object is not subscriptable
```

And on Python 3:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I fix this, please?

Comment: `G.predecessors(v)` is returning an iterator, and one cannot index into an iterator. If you need to be able to index into it often, you should convert it to either a list or a tuple. Ex. `list(G.predecessors(v))`, then you can index it as you like: `list(G.predecessors(v))[0]`

Comment: What kind of object is `G`? You just say it's "an object" in your question, which is not very helpful. Is it an instance of a class you've created, if so then you might be able to fix the issue by changing the definition of `predecessors`. But if it comes from a library, you'll need a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is returning an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) (that can be iterated element by element exactly once, destructively), not a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) (that can be indexed, iterated repeatedly, etc.).

If you just want to pull the first element from the iterator and discard the rest, change the code to:

```
u = next(G.predecessors(v))
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if *nothing* is in the iterator at all, otherwise, it returns the first value. To make it silently return a default when the iterator is empty, pass a second argument to `next`, e.g. to get `None`:

```
u = next(G.predecessors(v), None)
```

If you need the first element, but might also need the rest later, a useful trick is unpacking:

```
u, *rest = G.predecessors(v)
```

which puts the first value in `u`, then stores the rest to a `list` named `rest` that can be indexed or iterated on demand. Or just convert the whole thing to a `list` and use it as such:

```
allvals = list(G.predecessors(v))
u = allvals[0]  # And do other stuff with it
```

Comment: but after this changed, it changes the error as

Comment: for v in nodes_remain:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: # consolidate edges and remove 1-in 1-out nodes in the suffix trie
nodes_remain = G.nodes()
for v in nodes_remain:
    if G.out_degree(v) < 2: 
        if G.in_degree(v) == 1 and G.out_degree(v) == 1:
            u = next(G.predecessors(v))
            w = next(G.successors(v))
            G.add_edge(u, w, label=G[u][v]['label']+G[v][w]['label'])
            G.remove_node(v)
result = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'label').values()

Comment: @MinoLiu: That's a completely different question, on code I can't possibly understand in a comment. You need to post a new question (don't edit this one, since the new question is effectively unrelated) and include a [MCVE], not just individual snippets of code that has only one of the many errors it looks like you've coded.